# How to get only the numbers(without whitespaces) from a text file in python

Tags: python, list, append, text-files

Hello i have this text file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 1 1 1 1 1
-1 1 -1 -1 -1 1
2 3 5 6 1 6
10 0 0.5 1 0 0
0 30 5 3 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 5
80 90 6 5,4 8 5
65 58 2 9,7 1 1
83 60 4 7,2 4 7
40 80 10 7,5 7 10
52 72 6 2 3 8
94 96 7 3,6 5 6
```

I want to append the 7 first lines in 7 different lists( with a for loop if it is possible) to look like this:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6]
b=[1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

and so one for the rest 5. And then i want the remaining 6 lines of the file to be appended in to a list of list with a for loop(so that if i have more than 6 remaining lines, the code would not change) like this:

```
mylol=[[80 90 6 5,4 8 5],[65 58 2 9,7 1 1],[83 60 4 7,2 4 7],[40 80 10 7,5 7 10],[52 72 6 2 3 8],[94 96 7 3,6 5 6]]
```

so that i will be able to use every number of every list of list as i want for mathematical operations. I noticed that in the end of the list of lists i try to make i have a list looking like this:

```
['']
```

and i dont want it if it is possible.

I have this code so far but i want something more like the one i ask for:

```
with open("c.txt") as file:
lines = []
for line in file:
    # The rstrip method gets rid of the "\n" at the end of each line
    lines.append(line.rstrip().split(","))
print lines
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: What does your code do? What output do you get from it?

Comment: well i get this: [['1 2 3 4 5 6'], ['1 1 1 1 1 1'], ['-1 1 -1 -1 -1 1'], ['2 3 5 6 1 6'], ['10 0 0.5 1 0 0'], ['0 30 5 3 0 0'], ['0 0 0 0 0 5'], ['80 90 6 5', '4 8 5'], ['65 58 2 9', '7 1 1'], ['83 60 4 7', '2 4 7'], ['40 80 10 7', '5 7 10'], ['52 72 6 2 3 8'], ['94 96 7 3', '6 5 6'], ['']]..but i want the first 7 lines appended seperatly in 7 lists and the 6 remaining in a list of lists without the empty list in the end [' ']

Comment: why can't you put everything in the same list and access lines 1 to 7 as list1[0].. list1[7] ?

Comment: @SilentMonk i'm pretty new to python and i dont have the logic yet...how could this be like?

Comment: @ThanosSmar, you need to provide more information as to what you want to do with the list. DO you want `7,5` to be converted to `7.5`? Do you want to store them as strings or numbers?

Comment: @ yes this was my mistake...i wrote below that i forgot to convert commas to dots before opening the file. Numbers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final_list = []
with open("c.txt") as f:
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        line_list = [float(n) for n in line.rstrip().replace(',', '.').split(" ")]
        if count < 7:
            final_list.append(line_list)
        else:
            if count == 7:
                final_list.append([])
            final_list[7].append(line_list)
        count += 1
```

This will output the first 7 lines in their own list and then the remaining lines will be added to a list in side the list outputting the following:

`[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.0, 6.0], [10.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 30.0, 5.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0], [[80.0, 90.0, 6.0, 54.0, 8.0, 5.0], [65.0, 58.0, 2.0, 97.0, 1.0, 1.0], [83.0, 60.0, 4.0, 72.0, 4.0, 7.0], [40.0, 80.0, 10.0, 75.0, 7.0, 10.0], [52.0, 72.0, 6.0, 2.0, 3.0, 8.0], [94.0, 96.0, 7.0, 36.0, 5.0, 6.0]]]`

It accounts for the comma that was supposed to be a decimal and interpolates the numbers as floats.

Answer (score 0):

`shlex` is your friend there https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html

```
with open("c.txt") as file:
lines = []
for line in file:
 # The rstrip method gets rid of the "\n" at the end of each line
 lines.append(shlex.split(line))
print lines
```

`shlex.split()` will do just as you want

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your lists to look like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Then the items have to be numbers (integer or float).

However, your input file has some items that look like this:

`5,4`

And that is neither an integer nor a float.

So, either you have to store your items as strings, which means you will see quote marks:

```
a = ['80', '90', '6', '5,4', '8', '5']
```

Or, you have to figure out some way of handling items like `5,4` so they can be converted into numbers.

## EDIT:

If you edit the file to change commas to periods, you could have this code:

```
with open("c.txt") as file:
lines = []
for line in file:
    current_line = []
    # The rstrip method gets rid of the "\n" at the end of each line
    for item in line.rstrip().split():
        if '.' in item:
            current_line.append(float(item))
        else:
            current_line.append(int(item))
    lines.append(current_line)
print lines
```

Comment: you are right...i forgot to change them from comma to dot to be int and floats....so what would the algorithm look like?